# How to check the availability of the calendar in google calendar

Tags: c#, botframework, google-api-dotnet-client, google-calendar-api

I'm building a chatbot and I'm adding the service of google calendar (to add event in a specific date and time).

I can add the event but i want to add the possibility to check if in that date /time i have available event to add.

This is my code :

```
 UserCredential credential;
            string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
               System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

            using (var stream =
           new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
               GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
               Scopes,
               "user",
               CancellationToken.None,
               new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            string ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API .NET Quickstart";

            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });


            Event newEvent = new Event()
            {
                //Summary = assuntoAgendamento,
                Summary = "Event",
                Location = "eee",
                Description = "Event is scheduled for:  " + eventi.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "  " + eventi.Time.ToShortTimeString(),
                Start = new EventDateTime()
                {

                    // DateTime = eventi.Date,
                    DateTime = new DateTime(eventi.Date.Year, eventi.Date.Month, eventi.Date.Day, eventi.Time.Hour, eventi.Time.Minute, 0),
                    TimeZone = "Europe/Brussels",


                },
                End = new EventDateTime()
                {

                       DateTime = eventi.Date.AddMinutes(60),
                   // DateTime = new DateTime(eventi.Date.Year, eventi.Date.Month, eventi.Date.Day, eventi.Time.Hour, eventi.Time.Hour +1 ,0),
                    TimeZone = "Europe/Brussels",
                },
                Recurrence = new String[] { "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1" },
                Attendees = new EventAttendee[] {
                new EventAttendee() { Email = "xxxxx@gmail.com" },


            },

                ///////////////////////////////////////////



                ///////////////////////////////////////////


                Reminders = new Event.RemindersData()
                {
                    UseDefault = false,
                    Overrides = new EventReminder[] {
                    new EventReminder() { Method = "email", Minutes = 1 * 60 },
                    new EventReminder() { Method = "sms", Minutes = 10 },
                }
                }
            };
            String calendarId = "primary";
            EventsResource.InsertRequest request1 = service.Events.Insert(newEvent, calendarId);
            Event createdEvent = request1.Execute();
            Console.WriteLine("Event created: {0}", createdEvent.HtmlLink);

            // Define parameters of request.
            EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
            request.TimeMin = eventi.Time;
            request.ShowDeleted = false;
            request.SingleEvents = true;
            request.MaxResults = 10;
            request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;


            // List events.
            Events events = request.Execute();
            Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:");
            if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
                {
                    string when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
                    {
                        when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, when);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No upcoming events found.");
            }
            Console.Read();

        }
```

Could you please advice me how to to this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add the possibility to check if in that date /time i have available event to add

To achieve your requirement: checking if new event with specified start time and end time overlaps other existing events, you can refer to the following code snippet.

```
if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
{
    var overlaplist = events.Items.Where(e => (Convert.ToDateTime(e.Start.DateTime) < eventi && Convert.ToDateTime(e.End.DateTime) > eventi.AddMinutes(60))
        || (Convert.ToDateTime(e.Start.DateTime) < eventi && Convert.ToDateTime(e.End.DateTime) > eventi)
        || (Convert.ToDateTime(e.Start.DateTime) > eventi && Convert.ToDateTime(e.Start.DateTime) < eventi.AddMinutes(60))
        || (Convert.ToDateTime(e.End.DateTime) > eventi && Convert.ToDateTime(e.End.DateTime) < eventi.AddMinutes(60))).ToList();

    if (overlaplist.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var eventItem in overlaplist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Date range of your new event overlaps with {0}, which start at {1} and end at {2})", eventItem.Summary, eventItem.Start.DateTime, eventItem.End.DateTime);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your new event is available!");
    }

}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No upcoming events found.");
}
```

***Test result:***

[image]

***Calendar events:***

[image]

Comment: You can also refer to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap) to compare two date ranges.